# Example 3.53 in Baby Rudin

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

Here's Example 3.53 in the book *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* by Walter Rudin, third edition.

> Consider the convergent series $$1 - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{5} - \frac{1}{6} + \ldots$$ and one of its rearrangements $$1 + \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{5} + \frac{1}{7} - \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{9} + \frac{1}{11} - \frac{1}{6} + \ldots$$ in which two positive terms are always followed by one negative. If $s$ is the sum of the original series, then $$s < 1 - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} = \frac{5}{6}.$$ Since $$\frac{1}{4k-3} + \frac{1}{4k-1} - \frac{1}{2k} = \frac{8k-4}{(4k-1)(4k-3)} - \frac{1}{2k} = \frac{2k(8k-4) - (4k-1)(4k-3)}{2k(4k-1)(4k-3)} = \frac{8k-3}{2k(4k-1)(4k-3)} > 0$$ for $k \geq 1$, we see that $$s^\prime_3 < s^\prime_6 < s^\prime_9 < \ldots,$$ where $s^\prime_n$ is the $n$th partial sum of the series after the rearrangement. Hence $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup s^\prime_n > s^\prime_3 = \frac{5}{6},$$ so that the rearranged series certainly does not converge to $s$.

Now here's my question:

> How to determine, using the machinery developed by Rudin upto this point in the book, if the new (or rearranged) series converges at all? Rudin leaves it to the reader to check that the new series does converge. How to prove this convergence?

I would like to have answers that use only the results that Rudin has discussed so far in the book.

Comment: Does the Leibniz test happen to be among those tools at your disposal?

Comment: What is that? I can't recall it using this name, I'm afraid.

Comment: Also known as the alternating series test. (Doesn't seem applicable here, however.)

Comment: Oh yes, it is Theorem 3.43 in Baby Rudin. Then what?

Comment: Not directly applicable, but unless I'm very much mistaken here, from there it's a very small step to prove the convergence - I believe that's what the answer below means to tell you.

Comment: Well, but I have yet to figure it out completely although I've managed to split the "third-step" series into a sum of two alternating series with monotonically decreasing terms in absolute value.

Comment: Okay, AST is applicable, but probably a bit more complicated than necessary. Added that, might help to clear up some of the confusion - sorry, was my bad.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We can show that the series converges, and find its sum, as follows:

$\hspace{.3 in}1 - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{5} - \frac{1}{6} + \cdots=\ln 2$ $\;\;\;$so

$\hspace{.27 in}\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{6}-\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{10}-\frac{1}{12}+\cdots=\frac{1}{2}\ln 2$.  $\;\;\;$Inserting zeros, we get

$\hspace{.26 in}0+\frac{1}{2}+0-\frac{1}{4}+0+\frac{1}{6}+0-\frac{1}{8}+0+\frac{1}{10}+\cdots=\frac{1}{2}\ln 2$.

Adding this to the original series gives

$\hspace{.26 in}1+0+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{5}+0+\frac{1}{7}-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{9}+0+\cdots=\frac{3}{2}\ln 2$, $\;\;$ so

$\hspace{.25 in} 1+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{7}-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{9}+\frac{1}{11}-\frac{1}{6}+\cdots=\frac{3}{2}\ln 2$.

Comment: Wow! What a great, clear answer!

Comment: @ignoramus Thanks!

Comment: @user84413 how did you figure it out yourself? Can you please enlighten me too as to how this insight came to you?

Comment: @SaaqibMahmuud I had seen this argument in some textbook -- it is not something I thought of myself.

Comment: This is all so good

Comment: Beautiful! Especially inserting zeros.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Notice that $s_{3k}'$ converge as $k \to \infty$. How far can $s_{3k+1}$ and $s_{3k+2}$ be from $s_{3k}$?

Comment: @D Poole, how do we know that $s_{3k}^\prime$ converges? And, how to use this information toward establishing the convergence of $s_n^\prime$?

Comment: For $s'_{3k}$ take a good look at the alternating series test. You have $(1+\frac{1}{3})-(\frac{1}{2})+(\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{7})-(\frac{1}{4}) \pm \cdots$ - now can you see how to separate this series and apply the test?

Comment: Is it like this? $$(1+ \frac{1}{3}) - \frac{1}{2} + (\frac{1}{5} + \frac{1}{7}) - \frac{1}{4} + (\frac{1}{9} + \frac{1}{11}) - \frac{1}{6} + \ldots =  (1 - \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{5} - \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{9} - \frac{1}{12} + \ldots) + (\frac{1}{3}  - \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{7} - \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{11} - \frac{1}{12} + \ldots).$$

Comment: I don't think that's quite what you want. Try to think of the following: Define the sequence $a_{2n-1}:=\frac{1}{4n-3}+\frac{1}{4n-1}$, $a_{2n}:=\frac{1}{n}$ for $n\geq 1$. Now, what does the alternating series test say about the series $\sum_{i=1}^\infty{(-1)^ia_i}$? And, how does that help you?

Comment: I'm afraid I'm unable to quite get your point. What's wrong with the way I've split it?

Comment: You might mean the very same thing here, actually, I'm just unable to see the structure in what you wrote here. I'm already writing an answer where I'll go into the question with a bit more detail.

Comment: To see that $s_{3k}'$ converge, look at the powers of $k$ in the fraction in your formula for $a_{3k-2}'+a_{3k-1}'+a_{3k}'$.

Comment: @DPoole Rudin has not discussed the regrouping of the terms of an infinite series. So rigor demands that we should confine ourselves to the results that Rudin has stated until Example 3.53.

Comment: @SaaqibMahmuud You do not need any results on rearrangements of infinite series for this method. It is an $\epsilon/2$ argument. Do you agree that you have the techniques to show that $s'_{3k}$ converges? If so, what is the largest that $|s'_{3k+1}-s'_{3k}|$ and $|s'_{3k+2}-s'_{3k}|$ can be? [For all  sufficiently large $N$, you have that $|s'_{N} - s'_{\lfloor N/3 \rfloor}|< \epsilon/2$. Further, since $s'_{3k}$ converges to $s',$ for instance, then for all $N'$ large enough, $|s'_{3N'}-s'|<\epsilon/2$. Putting these together $ \ldots$]

Comment: @DPoole it would have been much better if you could please supply all this detail in your answer, rather than necessitating such a long chain of comments as this! Counting on your empathy!